# Parametric equation representation of a parabola's portion

Tags: parametric

The question states: The portion of the parabola $y=x^2+7$ from $(-5,32)$ to $(4,23)$.

Since the $x$-values increase, what I did was write $x=-5+t$.

Then, I did $y=x^2+7=(-5+t)^2+7=t^2-10t+32$.

I gave the $t$-values from $t=0$ to $t=9$. This ensures that $x$-values are from $-5$ to $4$, and $y$-values are from $32$ to $23$.

But I got the answer marked incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your parametrisation is correct. but there are many answers. $x=t; y=t^2+7$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Can I use $x=t; y=t^2+7$?

Comment: And then $t=-5$ to $t=4$?

Comment: Yes you can, that is the easiest one.